# Cannot run pmdarima in google data lab. Its giving an error .ufunc size changed,

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to run from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima. Its giving me an error 
numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 216 from C header, got 192 from PyObject

on intalling pmdarima !pip install pmdarima

```
   Requirement already up-to-date: pmdarima in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.6.0)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.17.3 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.18.4)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pandas>=0.19 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.22.0)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.22)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scikit-learn>=0.22 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.22.2.post1)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=1.3.2 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (1.4.1)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Cython>=0.29 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.29.17)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: statsmodels>=0.10.2 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.11.1)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pmdarima) (0.14.1)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->pmdarima) (2.5.0)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->pmdarima) (2018.4)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: patsy>=0.5 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from statsmodels>=0.10.2->pmdarima) (0.5.0)
    Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas>=0.19->pmdarima) (1.10.0)
```

numpy is updated too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an [issue with numpy](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/272). You need to downgrade to the version 1.16.1.

```
!pip install numpy==1.16.1
```

Then you need to restart the kernel so the change takes effect

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```